Setting up auto build TS to JS for Salesforce + LWC + VsCode
I wanna use TS in our project. Part of team using VsCode, second part using IntelijIdea. With IntelijIdea everything fine - ts code building to js automatically, but for VsCode need invoke npx tsc --project ./path/to/lwc every time manually. So, we need to automize it. Important point - setting must be placed in the git repo, to more fast start work with project for new members. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
